# Other coreference resolution alternatives

Tags: java, python, nlp, stanford-nlp

I'm working a project that requires use of coreference resolution for sentences. I tried out the Stanford CoreNLP's coreference resolution and it works fine, though it does noticeably and expectedly run slower for larger pieces of text I'm analyzing.

Could anyone suggest alternative coreference resolution tools that may run faster than Stanford's? (Preferably in Java or Python)

Comment: This should probably be moved to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Will do. Didn't know about that site.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try the [Berkeley Coreference Resolution System](http://nlp.cs.berkeley.edu/projects/coref.shtml) (superceded by the [Berkeley Entity Resolution System](http://nlp.cs.berkeley.edu/projects/entity.shtml) or the [Illinois Coreference Package](http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/page/software_view/Coref). All of them run on the JVM (first two are in Scala).